# how to set my image example number as image number

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing, numbering

I have application with which I am generating my PDF from various chapters and sections, by adding and removing chapter and sections. So I found problem with example numbers and image numbers. For example I am writing in chapter 2 that `Something is shown on example image (2.1)` and there is `image 2.1`. But if I remove `chapter 1`, my `chapter 2`, becomes `chapter 1` and my image number is `1.1`, not `2.1` . How can I set my example numbers correct?

Thanks.

Comment: That is what \label and \ref is for.

Comment: Yes I am using \label to set image number, so how to set in text a number of that image? If you can make me an example. Lets say I want to say: `Something is shown in image (image number)`

Comment: what if I use my example few times and after another examples? I use  ` \label{fig:image15}`  maybe I should rename it somehow every label in different name?

Comment: The linked answer provides the objective, which is similar to what you're looking for. Place `\label{<whatever>}` within your environment - *after* `\caption` if inside a `figure` or `table` - and `\ref{<whatever>}` within your document body.

Comment: but if my \label is always same :) what then? but numbering works perfectly

Comment: @Mantas: It is good practice to use descriptive names for `\label`s, especially since they may change. For example, `\label{fig:trees}` is more descriptive than `\label{fig:image15}`. You have to choose a *unique* `\label` for each object. That's the law.

Comment: so you offer to change every `\label{fig:name}`name?

Answer (score 0):

\label{name} stores \thefigure together with "name" in the aux file.  More accurately, it stores the counter last incremented by \refstepcounter.
\ref{name} retrieves this stored text, but it takes a second run to show changes.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Start}
See Figure \ref{name}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{test}\label{name}% must come after \caption
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```